# Best practice for uniform buffer in Vulkan

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

Let me say my way of uniform buffering first, I have a buffer in device local memory and one (for staging) in host coherent memory, and each is divided to number-of-framebuffers sections, in each frame, before beginning render pass, I update the host located one and then copy that to device located and I wait till the command buffer ends.

(Assume that my GPU is a discrete one with no shared memory between CPU and GPU)

Now my questions:

- Is it a best way for managing uniform buffer with staging and copying in each frame?
- Indeed, I know the synchronization mechanism I use, is not OK, what is the best way for doing so?
- If your answer is to do barrier synchronization, what is the exact way of doing that? (because I have not seen any sample like this.)

Till here every sample code I have seen, use host coherent uniform buffers, I will be appreciated if you refer a sample code for something like this.

Comment: Did You see this post: http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/vulkan/2017/08/13/Vulkan-Uniform-Buffers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised you have a device without a HOST_VISIBLE heap that uniform buffers can be located in. Using the CPU to write into the same buffer that the GPU reads from is often the best path, and I thought all modern GPUs supported that.

But if you really need a host->device copy, then you want to make sure to start the copies early enough that they're done by the time the graphics pipeline is ready to use them, and use a transfer-only queue to do the copy. This will overlap the copy with other earlier work, so the graphics pipeline is never sitting idle waiting for it. To do that:

1. Write the uniforms for a frame into the host buffer.
2. Submit a command buffer with the host->device copy commands to the transfer queue, and put a `VkSemaphore` in `VkSubmitInfo::pSignalSemaphores`.
3. Finish any remaining work for the frame rendering command buffers, and submit them to the graphics queue with the earlier semaphore in the `VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphores` list. Unfortunately, since some of the uniforms are probably needed in the vertex shader, `*pWaitDstStageMask` will need to be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT`.

If you're GPU-limited, hopefully the transfer for frame N+1 happens while the graphics pipeline is still working on frame N. You might need a tool like GPUView or Radeon Graphics Profiler to see if this is happening properly.

Comment: By host visibility for uniform I mean this https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/eb4fec7edb42b6e42832c6a0c42a02fe528231b0/examples/triangle/triangle.cpp#L1035 
so you are telling that this is the best way for creating/using uniform buffer?

Comment: The "may affect performance" comment probably refers to using the HOST_COHERENT flag. If you don't use a HOST_COHERENT memory type, you need to use vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges after writing to the buffer, and before the GPU starts using it (usually, before vkQueueSubmit, though you can get fancy with fences to do it after submit if you have a reason to). Your usage pattern is regular enough that it's probably not too inconvenient to use vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges.